# How to run migration file in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I got file 20180423091126_create_reference_book.exs

```
defmodule Simula.Repo.Migrations.CreateReferenceBook do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:reference_books) do
      add(:owner_id, :integer, default: 0)
      add(:owner_entity, :text, default: "")
      add(:name, :text, default: "")
      # количество уровней 0 - не ограничено
      add(:levels, :integer, default: 1)
      add(:entity, :text, default: "")
      add(:props, :map)
      add(:status, :integer, default: 1)
    end
  end
end
```

I made new project via $ mix new project1. Then put migration file in lib folder. I try to do $ iex -S mix, but I get the error.

```
** (CompileError) lib/reference_item.ex:2: module Ecto.Schema is not loaded and could not be found
```

How to make migration right?

Comment: The migration definitions should be in `priv/repo/migrations`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are creating new project with `mix new project1`, it will create a plain `elixir` project. You have to follow three steps.

1. Adding ecto as dependency in `mix.exs`

   ```
   {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
   {:ecto, "~> 2.1"}
   ```
2. Adding configuration to connect to database in `config.exs`

   ```
   config :project1, ecto_repos: [Project1.Repo]

   config :project1, Project1.Repo,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
    database: "project1",
    username: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: "5432"
   ```
3. Adding a Repo module in `repo.ex` under lib directory.

   ```
   defmodule Project1.Repo do
    use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :two
   end
   ```

After that you can either create a new migration using `mix ecto.gen.migration create_reference_book` which will create a file for you in `priv/repo/migrations/20180513070540__create_reference_book.exs` and you can paste the content or manually create a directory `priv/repo/migrations/` and paste your file.

Finally run `mix ecto.create` to create database and `mix ecto.migrate` to create tables in the database.